# The range for a relaxed state/normal state/stressful state using a Galvanic Skin Response (skin conductance )

Tags: arduino

I want to measure Skin conductance using Galvanic Skin sensor. I use Arduino software.

[image: When I measure skin conductance using GSR,I got values like this in normal situation]

So I want to know the actual value range for a relaxed person and for a stressed person.
Also I want to know What is the actual unit for this measurement.

This is my ardiuno source code .

```
const int LED=13;
const int GSR=A2;
int threshold=0;
int sensorValue;

void setup(){
  long sum=0;
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED,LOW);
  delay(1000);

  for(int i=0;i<500;i++)
  {
  sensorValue=analogRead(GSR);
  sum += sensorValue;
  delay(5);
  }
  threshold = sum/500;
   Serial.print("threshold =");
   Serial.println(threshold);
  }

void loop(){
  int temp;
  sensorValue=analogRead(GSR);
  Serial.print("sensorValue=");
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  temp = threshold - sensorValue;

 }
}
```

Comment: Read the datasheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
analogRead(GSR);
```

This gives you value from 0~1023, you need to map it to a certain range, or do some calculations.
Check datasheet, or provide us, the sensor's name.

Comment: Yeh I found that that the normal range for a  relaxed person  is 2-20 micro seaman. The problem is I have no idea how to map it with my output values.

Comment: What's the sensor's name ?

Comment: **Wadaane** ,It is Galvanic Skin Response Sensor(GSR)

Comment: I checked it and from what I understood the sensor only gives you a "change" in emotions, not an actual value​.